# Hex package in C

Tags: c, tcp, hex

I have a CLinux device that gets a trigger from a serial device - then transforms some data - and outputs through TCP to another device (server).

The server needs to get the data like:

**|STX|0x04|0x41 0x01|DATA-BYTECOUNT-WORD|Option-BYTE|FIELDNUMBER-BYTE|ASCII STRING|ETX|**

I can only achieve what i want using a 3rd party software, Hercules ( image below).
I was sniffing the data with wireshark and it is as follows in the green square.

[image: Hercules + Wireshark]

And this is the C code that I am using.

```
//var definition
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
char testOutput[ ] = {0x02,0x04,0x41,0x01,
                      0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                      0x31,0x31,0x20,0x31,
                      0x31,0x20,0x31,0x31,
                      0x31,0x31,0x03};
//example

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char* message[1000], server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if( sock == -1 )
    {
        printf( "Could not create socket" );
    }
    puts( "Socket created" );

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "192.168.0.180" );
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 3490 );

    if( connect( sock, ( struct sockaddr * )&server, sizeof( server ) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "Failed to connect to Server Machine.\n" );
    }
    puts( "Connected to Machine.\n" );

    //keep communicating with server - there's a trigger for each Send before this
    while( 1 )
    {
        if( send( sock, testOutput, 19, 0 ) < 0 )
        {
            puts( "Send failed." );
            break;
        }
    }
    close( sock );
    return 0;
}
```

With the code, i have a "visual" proper output in the console, although it doesn't show in the proper way in the server machine.

I've tried different output formats, once HEX can be transmitted as **char[]** , and it is plain text..
Why am i getting a different output from the one i get with hercules?

How can i reproduce the output like the one showed in Hercules?

EDIT-----

Based on an input char string like 
`char mytest[] = 020441010C0000003131203131203131313103`

How can i achieve:

`mytest2[] = {0x02,0x04,0x41,0x01,                          0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x31,0x31,0x20,0x31,0x31,0x20,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x03}`

I believe i need to split by 2, but i'm afraid that it will not format properly.
If someone helps me here i can get the answer myself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Giving context and showing the code is good and is really appreciated here. But asking an answerable question is also expected :-). I can see only one question here *Can someone help me there?* Well, maybe... More seriously, you should now say what your current problem is. [ask] contains valuable advices...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you for the advice. I will update, but the question is based on the picture.. why am i not getting the output as the one i get on the green square?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question entirely, but if the green square is what you want, and the red squares are what you're getting it seems like you're transmitting the data as ASCII when you want it to be binary 

It seems like you've posted one set of code and three different outputs so far, though. Can you post what you've tried and which output it's corresponded to?

Comment: Your `testHex` data looks implausible - you have binary data in an ASCII packet.  What is the format of the checksum (length, encoding)? A "Hex checksum" would comprise ASCII characters `'0'`-`'9'`, `'A'`-`'F'`, whereas you have binary  `0x04,0x41,0x01,0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x00` (an unlikely 7 bytes).  Then you treat it as a string where the first 0x00 will indicate the end rather than the ETX.  The code is clearly wrong, but the specification is also ambiguous, so it is not easy to determine the necessary correction.

Comment: @bearda the red output are exactly what i've tried.. sending as fully ascii, fully binary etc.. i just can't replicate what i can achieve with Hercules Hex mode ( see edit ).

Comment: @SE-LM what you have tried should be exemplified by the code.  The code you provided clearly did not produce either of those outputs.  And you have made a rather bizarre assumption that we all know what "Hercules" is and what it does.

Comment: You appear to completely misunderstand what your mystery Hercules software is doing. The Hex option clearly does not change the output, that is simply a matter of data entry and presentation format. It is slowing you to enter binary data in hexadecimal notation, and is presenting the data in that form. I the data sent and received remains _binary_. Your original code and the length correction in my answer should go a long way to solving your problem, but I fear that is no longer the code you are working with and are trying to apply the fix to something to which it may not apply.

Comment: @Clifford sorry for the assumption, but it was only a question. Regarding the `the code you provided clearly not produce either of those outputs` is false, case the last red square is exactly what you've asked me to do on the answer below.

Comment: @SE-LM Clearly we cannot work like this.  You have presented one version of the code, and three different outputs from different code. My suggested correction applies only to the _exact_ code presented in the question.

Comment: @Clifford let's make it easier. How can i get an output like the one produced in Hercules? Meanwhile i will update the question. TY

Comment: @SE-LM Easier would entail a simpler question, where you describe the output you want, the output you are getting and the code that is generating it. Exclude all other output from either tools that are not your code, or attempts for which you are not showing the code or in languages you are not interested in. The required output is now clear, it is the actual output and the exact code generating it that is ambiguous.

Comment: @Clifford i've updated the question. How do i get the proper output, based on constant size etc?

Comment: The edit is clearer but you have now only shown the expected output, not  the actual output.  Moreover you have changed the code rendering the existing answer nonsense - people why take the effort to answer seldom appreciate that.

Comment: Why woyld you use a literal constant for the size? `sizeof(testOutput)` is also a constant size.

Comment: @Clifford I made a couple of changes, and if i add the input string like `testOutput` i can make it work. Now i just need to figure out how to change a char string to a char array ( sorry for wrong sintax).

Comment: You are _still_ misunderstanding the Wireshark output I think.  The code you have appears to be correct.  The Wireshark output is a hexadecimal representation of the binary data, not a data _string_.  If you actually need to send the binary data using hexadecimal encoding, then that is a different question.  But that is not what your Hercules example shows.  I think this is probably correct, your problem may be elsewhere - such as your I interpretation of the requirements.